# Is it possible to view a specific tag by default on the SE android application?

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app

I would like to have specific tags open by default. Is there a way in the settings menu?

If there is not, could you consider to implement it?

Requirement:
All tag or selected tag to view in the specific group or over the joined group

For example:

When someone has several groups joined such Ask Different, Super User and StackOverfollow. There are many Tags ready and used in each group. But He might be necessary to check only about specific tags. If there is a function to check the specific tag over the joined groups or in the group, It might be easier to check and respond the question, and to grab knowledge more about the area.

Comment: Not really a good idea. Perhaps a list of `Favorite Tags` might be useful, but doesn't seem so important now.

Answer (score -1):

Tag brings identity that explain the main topic of the question.

Tag categorize an question and make it distinguishable to be answered by specific people in the related subject (expert, enthusiast, etc.)

Therefore, In my opinion, we need more reason to put a default tag to the question. The possible drawback is that it will make the question bias.

Anyhow, this is an interesting topic to be discussed. Thanks